# there are INNER JOIN limits - part 2?

Tags: mysql, join

I have asked before a question about INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN, but I still with no answers about the LIMIT to use INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN in my query.

**The Situation:** I have 11 tables of different kinds of material that I need to check every time when I need to retrieve information about what material was used in a instalation.

The install have a list of material, sometimes the install is full sometimes not, if full instalation I need to check the eleven possible tables of material, I would like to use a single query, or better a single huge query.

Is it possible?

Thanks anyway, is just a curiosity. :)

**[EDITED]**
**the table structure**

```
--
-- Estrutura da tabela `equipment`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `equipment` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idcontrato` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idtorre` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `tipo_equip` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `obs` text NOT NULL,
  `usado_cliente` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'usado no cliente 1=sim 0=nao',
  `cod_equip` varchar(25) NOT NULL COMMENT 'codigo para controle de equipamento',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='equipamentos apenas para router e antenas' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `equipment`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `equip_antena`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `equip_antena` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cod_equip` varchar(25) NOT NULL COMMENT 'codigo para controle de equipamento',
  `unid_medida` enum('metros','unidade','peça','pacote') DEFAULT NULL,
  `qtde` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idproduto` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'id do produto na tbl produtos',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='tbl de equipamento instalado no cliente' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `equip_antena`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `equip_antena_cable_rgc213`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `equip_antena_cable_rgc213` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cod_equip` varchar(25) NOT NULL COMMENT 'codigo para controle de equipamento',
  `unid_medida` enum('metros','unidade','peça','pacote') DEFAULT NULL,
  `qtde` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idantena` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'id do produto na tbl produtos',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='tbl de equipamento instalado no cliente ' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `equip_antena_cable_rgc213`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `equip_cable_utp`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `equip_cable_utp` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cod_equip` varchar(25) NOT NULL COMMENT 'codigo para controle de equipamento',
  `unid_medida` enum('metros','unidade','peça','pacote') DEFAULT NULL,
  `qtde` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idantena` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'id do produto na tbl produtos',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='tbl de equipamento instalado no cliente ' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `equip_cable_utp`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `equip_conector`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `equip_conector` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cod_equip` varchar(25) NOT NULL COMMENT 'codigo para controle de equipamento',
  `unid_medida` enum('metros','unidade','peça','pacote') DEFAULT NULL,
  `qtde` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idantena` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'id do produto na tbl produtos',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='tbl de equipamento instalado no cliente ' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `equip_conector`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `equip_conector2`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `equip_conector2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cod_equip` varchar(25) NOT NULL COMMENT 'codigo para controle de equipamento',
  `unid_medida` enum('metros','unidade','peça','pacote') DEFAULT NULL,
  `qtde` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idantena` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'id do produto na tbl produtos',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='tbl de equipamento instalado no cliente ' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `equip_conector2`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `equip_fonte`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `equip_fonte` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cod_equip` varchar(25) NOT NULL COMMENT 'codigo para controle de equipamento',
  `unid_medida` enum('metros','unidade','peça','pacote') DEFAULT NULL,
  `qtde` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idantena` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'id do produto na tbl produtos',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='tbl de equipamento instalado no cliente ' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `equip_fonte`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `equip_pigtail`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `equip_pigtail` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cod_equip` varchar(25) NOT NULL COMMENT 'codigo para controle de equipamento',
  `unid_medida` enum('metros','unidade','peça','pacote') DEFAULT NULL,
  `qtde` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idproduto` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'id do produto na tbl produtos',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='tbl de equipamento instalado no cliente ' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `equip_pigtail`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `equip_poe`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `equip_poe` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cod_equip` varchar(25) NOT NULL COMMENT 'codigo para controle de equipamento',
  `unid_medida` enum('metros','unidade','peça','pacote') DEFAULT NULL,
  `qtde` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idantena` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'id do produto na tbl produtos',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='tbl de equipamento instalado no cliente ' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `equip_poe`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `equip_rj45`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `equip_rj45` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cod_equip` varchar(25) NOT NULL COMMENT 'codigo para controle de equipamento',
  `unid_medida` enum('metros','unidade','peça','pacote') DEFAULT NULL,
  `qtde` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idproduto` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'id do produto na tbl produtos',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='tbl de equipamento instalado no cliente ' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `equip_rj45`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `equip_router`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `equip_router` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cod_equip` varchar(25) NOT NULL COMMENT 'codigo para controle de equipamento',
  `unid_medida` enum('metros','unidade','peça','pacote') DEFAULT NULL,
  `qtde` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idproduto` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'id do produto na tbl produtos',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='tbl de equipamento instalado no cliente ' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `equip_router`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `equip_suporte`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `equip_suporte` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cod_equip` varchar(25) NOT NULL COMMENT 'codigo para controle de equipamento',
  `unid_medida` enum('metros','unidade','peça','pacote') DEFAULT NULL,
  `qtde` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idantena` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'id do produto na tbl produtos',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='tbl de equipamento instalado no cliente ' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `equip_suporte`
--


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `equip_suporte2`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `equip_suporte2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cod_equip` varchar(25) NOT NULL COMMENT 'codigo para controle de equipamento',
  `unid_medida` enum('metros','unidade','peça','pacote') DEFAULT NULL,
  `qtde` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idantena` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'id do produto na tbl produtos',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='tbl de equipamento instalado no cliente ' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `equip_suporte2`
--
```

Comment: Could you please post the structure of your tables?

Comment: the commom field is cod_equip  (code equipment) I thought I can use JOIN on this field, but if has an other approach.. I m all ears. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add as many joins as you want/need, as far as I know there's no limit. It might get slower though, depending on the amount of data it needs to search through. You can look into INDEXES to speed up matching up data between different tables.

Here's an example:

I'm assuming (maybe wrongfully so, but doesn't matter for the example) that the `equipment` table is the main equipment, and it's possible that there are other types of equipment linked to that.

The choice between INNER or LEFT JOIN is simple: if there's always an entry in all these other tables, you can use INNER. If there *might be* an entry, but there doesn't have to be one, you should use LEFT JOIN. That way you'll simply retrieve certain data from the main table (`SELECT .. FROM main WHERE ..`) and if there are matches in one of these LEFT JOINed tables, they'll be added to the main results.

```
SELECT
    e.*
  , ea.id AS antena
  , ecu.id AS cable_utp
FROM equipment e
LEFT JOIN equip_antena ea
  ON ea.cod_equip = e.cod_equip
LEFT JOIN equip_cable_utp ecu
  ON ecu.cod_equip = e.cod_equip
WHERE e.id = 1
```

This will show you the information from the `equipment` table where id = 1. If there's an `equip_antena` entry with the same `cod_equip` id, the column "antena" will be set, otherwise it will be NULL. The same goes for a possible entry in `equip_cable_utp`. And you can do this for all the other tables as well.

Comment: First thanks for your answer <b>@Alec:</b> <i>"You can add as many joins as you want/need, as far as I know there's no limit."</i> --- I will do exactly like this, I think I do not Index 'cause all this tables will not grow too much, and it will be a kind of process running in background. Thank Very much for your answer.

Comment: my problems about INNER or LEFT JOIN, Actually I do not know if always 'll have an entry in all tables, sometimes the entry is in all tables but sometimes is not. What to do in this case? using INNER even if do not has an entry in all tables?

Comment: Say you `SELECT * FROM foo INNER JOIN bar ON bar.foo_id = foo.id`, you will only get a result if there's a match between both these tables. If there isn't an entry in `bar` with a matching foo_id, you won't see anything. So that would be perfect for selecting _only_ those entries to which certain types of equipment are linked. But when you need the main result that _possibly_ has a match in another table, use LEFT JOIN. Always start with selecting from the main table, and figure out what kind of a result you want.